# Android studio - release APK for flavor

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I'm new to Android Studio and running a debug build on a device is working fine, however to test in app purchasing (and obviously to release) I need a release build signed with the normal key.  I can make an APK using Build -> Generate signed APK, however the package name seems to be incorrect.  Here's my build file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 9

        testPackageName "com.company.common.common"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.common.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file("filname")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        Flavor1 {
            packageName "com.company.test"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // some dependencies
}
```

Note the package name overridden in the flavor.  That flavor has no manifest; the only manifest is under main, and specifies a package of com.company.common.  If I use Android to create a com.company.test APK and install it on a device, then generate an APK from Android Studio and install it, I end up with two apps on the device rather than the second replacing the first.  This indicates that the package names are different, I assume because Android Studio is producing an APK with a package of com.company.common.  Not sure how to verify that though.

When I just build the project, I get a debug APK but no release APK.  How do I get a release APK with the correct package name?  I just ran the app from Android Studio and it says it's installing com.company.test.debug, and that it needs to uninstall the app before installing.  So now I'm thinking the generate signed APK generated a build with the debug package.

So far this is the issue that's preventing me from moving to Android Studio and gradle.  Once I get past this I think I'm clear to move everything over so I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out!

Comment: I use "gradle assembleRelease" on the commandline to make sure I'm creating a release build. You should also be able to test with the "installFlavor1Release" task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you choose the **Generate Signed APK** option, go into the **Build Variants** window and choose the **Release** build variant. The **Generate Signed APK** command takes whatever the current build type is selected there and signs it. This obviously isn't what you want in this case; bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56532 is requesting improvements there.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  From my reading of the documentation, it seems like I should be able to set it up so that when I build the project, it automatically produces a debug APK and a release APK, without having to go to Generate signed APK.  Am I misunderstanding, or is my configuration wrong, or could it be a bug in AS?

Comment: There's no such thing as an unsigned APK -- even debug builds are signed with a debug key. So if you build your release build via command line or normal build command in Android Studio, it will be signed with the key specified in your build.gradle file, which is what you set up with the Generate Signed APK wizard -- it's all the same. The wizard just fills out the entries in your build file if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes I know, what I'm saying is when I just do a build (Ctrl-F9), it produces a signed debug APK, and that's it.  No release APK.  Since I have all the signing information in the gradle build file, is there a way to get it to also produce a signed release APK with each build?  Or do I always have to go to Build -> Generate signed APK?

Comment: You don't need to use the Generate Signed APK command. If your currently chosen build type from the Build Variants window is Release, then Ctrl-F9 should build it. There's no way through the UI to have it build both at the same time, every time, when you press Ctrl-F9. You could probably set up a single Gradle task you could execute to build both, but it would be tricky to hook that up to an actual build type you could invoke from Ctrl-F9.